# Python: Constructing text to pass through to a class in wxpython

Tags: python

My question is very poorly worded but I'm trying to concatenate (or construct) text that is passed through my wxpython script. For example...

Normally I would request the value in the wxpython GUI by:

```
a = frame.L100ENABLE.GetValue()
```

I want to be able to construct the center expression:

```
a = frame.+"L"+"100"+"ENABLE".GetValue()
```

I'm not sure how to do that part...

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Read Python docs about `getattr()`

Comment: So I tried doing getattr() and maybe I'm doing something wrong. It doesn't allow a string in the first argument and I can't include all of L100ENABLE.GetValue in the second argument. getattr(string, GetValue) doesn't work because it looks for the attribute in str. I also tried getattr(frame, "L100ENABLE.GetValue") but that did not work either.

Comment: `a = getattr(frame, "L"+"100"+"ENABLE").GetValue()` should work.

Comment: That was it!! Thank you Michael